# Normal Operator: Empty Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

For normal operators:
$$N^*N=NN^*:\quad\sigma(N)\neq\varnothing$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every bounded linear operator on a complex Banach space has non-empty spectrum $\sigma(B)$. A simple way to argue this is to assume the contrary, and conclude that $(B-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is an entire function of $\lambda$ which vanishes at $\infty$; then Liouville's theorem gives the contradiction that $(B-\lambda I)^{-1}\equiv 0$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

If $N$ is unbounded normal and has empty spectrum, then $N^{-1}$ is bounded and has spectrum $\sigma(N^{-1})\subseteq\{0\}$ because, for $\lambda\ne 0$,
$$
    (N^{-1}-\lambda I) =(I-\lambda N)N^{-1}=\lambda(\frac{1}{\lambda}I-N)N^{-1}
$$
has bounded inverse
$$
               \frac{1}{\lambda}N\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}I-N\right)^{-1}.
$$
Spectral radius and norm are the same for a bounded normal operator, which leads to the contradiction that $N^{-1}=0$.

Comment: Nice proof - thanks :) so but then my question is the closure of the numerical range always the convex hull of the spectrum of a selfadjoint operator even for unbounded ones?

Comment: @Freeze_S : I added information for you about numerical range, but I assume the spectral theorem.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line read: "Spectral radius and norm are the same for an *unbounded* selfadjoint operator, ..." Assuming a bounded operator would relate to the former paragraph, or? Besides your answer greatly applies to normal operators, too. Do you mind replacing selfadjoint by normal? *(I would adapt the question then.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : No, spectral radius and norm are the same for a *bounded* selfadjoint operator. Norm doesn't exist for an unbounded operator. So I reduce the unbounded case to the bounded by knowing that some point is in the resolvent.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot that the inverse is bounded. _*dough*_ Still, love that proof!!

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan : If $N$ is unbounded with empty spectrum, then, $N^{-1}$ is bounded because, by assumption, $0$ is in the resolvent set.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to make a separate answer for the Numerical Range question. They're different. Yes, the closure of the numerical range is the same as the closed convex hull of the spectrum.

**Numerical Range:** Suppose $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} \in \sigma(A)$ with $\lambda_{1}\ne \lambda_{2}$. Using the spectral theorem, you can find sequences $\{ e_{1,n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{ e_{2,n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of unit vectors in the domain of $A$ such that $e_{1,n},Ae_{1,n}$ are orthogonal to $e_{2,n},Ae_{2,n}$, and such that
$$
                \lim_{n}(Ae_{j,n},e_{j,n})=\lambda_{j},\;\;\; j =1,2.
$$
Then, for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, let $e_{n}=\alpha e_{1,n}+\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}e_{2,n}$, which is a unit vector, and
$$
\begin{align}
    (Ae_{n},e_{n})
         & = \alpha^{2}(Ae_{1,n},e_{1,n})+(1-\alpha^{2})(Ae_{2,n},e_{2,n}), \\
   \lim_{n}(Ae_{n},e_{n}) & = \alpha^{2}\lambda_{1}+(1-\alpha^{2})\lambda_{2}.
\end{align}
$$
So the closure of the numerical range $\mathscr{N}(A)$ includes the closed convex hull of the spectrum. Conversely, suppose $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ is a unit vector. Let $E$ be the spectral resolution of the identity for $A$. Then $\mu_{x}(S)=\|E(S)x\|^{2}$ is a probability measure and
$$
                        (Ax,x) = \int_{\sigma} \lambda d\mu_{x}(\lambda).
$$
So, the numerical range $\mathscr{N}(A)$ is contained in the closed convex hull of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the spectrum of any operator can't be [empty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)). I think what you mean is that the operator might not have an eigenvalue- an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators) is given here.

Comment: Side note: For general **unbounded** operators, the spectrum can be empty, but for self adjoint operators (even unbounded), the spectrum is always nonempty.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Do you have some good reference on these issues for further reading?

Comment: @voldemort: I mean spectrum of unbounded operator. *(The bounded case is clear.)*

Comment: @C-Star-W-Star Let $A=\frac{d}{dx}$ on the dense domain $\mathcal{D}(A)\subset L^2[0,1]$ consisting of all absolutely continuous $f\in L^2$ such that $f'\in L^2$ and $f(0)=0$. $(A-\lambda I)f=g$ is uniquely solved for $f\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ with $f=e^{\lambda x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda u}f(u)du$, and this defines a bounded operator on $L^2$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: And it has necessarily empty spectrum since it is not closed?

Comment: @C-star-W-star The spectrum of a non-closed operator is always the entire complex plane, since for a non-closed operator $A$ the inverse $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is non-closed and hence surely not bounded. The operator given by DisintegratingByParts is closed.